# Adding real time Voice filter with web audio api

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to implement real time voice changer, I have tried some methods but I could not get any results.

I have tried to implement my codes according to following tutorial [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource)

According to the link above, instead of using bufferSource, I created the source from the stream with createMediaStreamSource and sent it to the demonBeastTransform method

here is my final codes:

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const range = document.querySelector("#gain");


navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => {
      video.play();
      video.muted = true;
    };

    // Create a MediaStreamAudioSourceNode
    // Feed the HTMLMediaElement into it
    const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    const source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    demonBeastTransform(source, audioCtx)

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`The following error occured: ${err}`);
  });

async function demonBeastTransform(source, ctx, distortionAmount = 100) {

  /*  let ctx = new OfflineAudioContext(audioBuffer.numberOfChannels, audioBuffer.length, audioBuffer.sampleRate); */

  // Source
  /*       let source = ctx.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioBuffer; */

  // Reverb
  let convolver = ctx.createConvolver();
  convolver.buffer = await ctx.decodeAudioData(await (await fetch("https://voicechanger.io/audio/impulse-responses/voxengo/Large Wide Echo Hall.wav")).arrayBuffer());


  // Fire
  let fire = ctx.createBufferSource();
  fire.buffer = await ctx.decodeAudioData(await (await fetch("https://voicechanger.io/audio/backgrounds/brush_fire-Stephan_Schutze-55390065.mp3")).arrayBuffer());
  fire.loop = true;

  // Compressor
  let compressor = ctx.createDynamicsCompressor();
  compressor.threshold.value = -50;
  compressor.ratio.value = 16;

  // Wobble
  let oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
  oscillator.frequency.value = 50;
  oscillator.type = 'sawtooth';
  // ---
  let oscillatorGain = ctx.createGain();
  oscillatorGain.gain.value = 0.004;
  // ---
  let delay = ctx.createDelay();
  delay.delayTime.value = 0.01;
  // ---
  let fireGain = ctx.createGain();
  fireGain.gain.value = 0.2;
  // ---
  let convolverGain = ctx.createGain();
  convolverGain.gain.value = 2;

  // Filter
  let filter = ctx.createBiquadFilter();
  filter.type = "highshelf";
  filter.frequency.value = 1000;
  filter.gain.value = 10;

  // Create graph
  oscillator.connect(oscillatorGain);
  oscillatorGain.connect(delay.delayTime);
  // ---
  source.connect(delay)
  delay.connect(convolver);
  //waveShaper.connect(convolver);

  fire.connect(fireGain);
  convolver.connect(convolverGain);

  convolverGain.connect(filter);
  filter.connect(compressor);

  fireGain.connect(ctx.destination);

  compressor.connect(ctx.destination);

  let filter2 = ctx.createBiquadFilter();
  filter2.type = "lowpass";
  filter2.frequency.value = 2000;
  let noConvGain = ctx.createGain();
  noConvGain.gain.value = 0.9;
  delay.connect(filter2);
  filter2.connect(filter);
  filter.connect(noConvGain);
  noConvGain.connect(compressor);

  // Render
  oscillator.start(0);
  source.start(0);
  fire.start(0);
  /*   let outputAudioBuffer = await ctx.startRendering();
    return outputAudioBuffer; */

}
```

```html
<h1>Web Audio API examples: MediaStreamAudioSourceNode</h1>
<video controls></video>
<br />
```

Comment: *I have tried some methods but I could not get any results.* Could you explain in more detail what the specific issue is? Do some parts work? Are you encountering errors?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier  I don't get any specific errors or even any errors. my main goal was to run the demonBeastTransform method in real time. I tried adapting the documentation in the link above to my own code, but I couldn't get any results either. I can hear my voice when I do false instead of `video.muted = true`. but i get the raw version of the sound. I couldn't get the filtered voice to work as in the documentation. I can't even hear a sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of tinkering a bit with your script and made the following modifications:

### Stream

The biggest change is how the stream is handled. Now the `demonBeastTransform` passes the `stream` object in to the function as its only argument.

The reason for this is that we need both the audio and video tracks from the stream. And the idea behind it is to split the audio and video tracks, modify the audio track and then combine them back together into a single stream that is passed as the `srcObject` of the video.

### CORS

The first issue I ran into is that the `fetch` requests weren't working because of a Same Origin Policy error. However, I was able to download the files and fetch them from my local server, so I'd recommend that you do the same.

Add a `try / catch` block around any awaited requests to handle them better in case of an error.

```
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const range = document.querySelector("#gain");

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
  })
  .then(demonBeastTransform)
  .then((stream) => {
    video.onloadedmetadata = () => video.play()
    video.srcObject = stream;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`The following error occured: ${err}`);
  });

async function demonBeastTransform(stream) {
  const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  const source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  const streamDestination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();

  // Get the video tracks and add them to the stream destination.
  const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
  for (const videoTrack of videoTracks) {
    streamDestination.stream.addTrack(videoTrack);
  }

  // Reverb
  let convolver = audioCtx.createConvolver();

  try {
    const convolerResponse = await fetch("Large Wide Echo Hall.wav");
    const convolverBuffer = await convolerResponse.arrayBuffer();
    convolver.buffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(convolverBuffer);
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

  // Fire
  let fire = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  
  try {
    const fireResponse = await fetch("brush_fire-Stephan_Schutze-55390065.mp3");
    const fireBuffer = await fireResponse.arrayBuffer();
    fire.buffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(fireBuffer);
    fire.loop = true;
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

  // Compressor
  let compressor = audioCtx.createDynamicsCompressor();
  compressor.threshold.value = -50;
  compressor.ratio.value = 16;

  // Wobble
  let oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  oscillator.frequency.value = 50;
  oscillator.type = 'sawtooth';
  // ---
  let oscillatorGain = audioCtx.createGain();
  oscillatorGain.gain.value = 0.004;
  // ---
  let delay = audioCtx.createDelay();
  delay.delayTime.value = 0.01;
  // ---
  let fireGain = audioCtx.createGain();
  fireGain.gain.value = 0.2;
  // ---
  let convolverGain = audioCtx.createGain();
  convolverGain.gain.value = 2;

  // Filter
  let filter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
  filter.type = "highshelf";
  filter.frequency.value = 1000;
  filter.gain.value = 10;

  // Create graph
  oscillator.connect(oscillatorGain);
  oscillatorGain.connect(delay.delayTime);
  // ---
  source.connect(delay)
  delay.connect(convolver);
  //waveShaper.connect(convolver);

  fire.connect(fireGain);
  convolver.connect(convolverGain);

  convolverGain.connect(filter);
  filter.connect(compressor);

  // Instead of audioCtx.destination we pass the audio into the new stream.
  fireGain.connect(streamDestination);
  compressor.connect(streamDestination);

  let filter2 = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
  filter2.type = "lowpass";
  filter2.frequency.value = 2000;

  let noConvGain = audioCtx.createGain();
  noConvGain.gain.value = 0.9;

  delay.connect(filter2);
  filter2.connect(filter);
  filter.connect(noConvGain);
  noConvGain.connect(compressor);

  // Render
  oscillator.start(0);
  fire.start(0);

  return streamDestination.stream;
}
```